# AWS EC2 : service file keep deleting while using composer update in AWS terminal

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I am using AWS EC2 LAMP server, when update or install any vendor library(require packages), my service.php file getting deleted, It's in `Project\bootstrap\catch\service.php` and getting error for all API calls.

**Some Time** - AWS Public IP changed while enter `composer update` in terminal once.